# Jquery Ajax not accessing callback when requested from file://

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, jsonp

I make a call from a html file on my PC. And get back illegal character, when it tries to access the callback. Error code 200, Jquery12133434 was not called.

It works fine from here http://jsfiddle.net/cwatw/

So my question is **How would I get this working from a file:// "url"**. Which must be the case as it is for a Windows 7 Gadget.

Note: I am using JSONP and getting a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ill be... I just found the solution after days of working on it.

In the Ajax part, add in the following.

```
scriptCharset: "utf-8",
```

That way it somehow understands the jsonp callback. What baffles me still is why this works without, as long as its not hosted from file://

Still not showing in the gadget mind, Must not load the same way. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle you are calling `data.toSource()` on your returned json `data`. That won't work. Try

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

Look like a valid object to me.